# Can we insert a new document at index that was already assigned to another doc?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongoose

Into my schema i have one field with `{ index : true }` via mongoose and named as 'my-index'.

When one doc is inserted with my-index say 23.

Now i want to insert another new doc at index 23. What i am doing is, i increase the my-index of the previous doc by one (that becomes 24). and after that i save the new doc with my-index 23.

When i switched back to mongo shell and found in db that, New document with my-index 23 was not able to be saved into db. And new document is absent in db.

Why is this so ?

and how do i make sure both document are able to be saved

Comment: I suspect that you are using the index to do something special that it is not designed to do, as with other database systems, indexes should be left to mongo to manage. If you told us what you are trying to achieve and for what purpose, you may get a better approach to your problem.

Comment: and please include actual documents and exact syntax you are executing and full output, otherwise we may be guessing about what's actually going on.

Comment: I don't think you understand what an `index` means for a database.

Comment: actually the problem behind is after sending the request, response data fetching takes very long time( abt 2 mins). in between while, only updating the previous doc has been done. however new doc could not be created. so there is delay. But why this delay is here, is unknown to me. Also this delay only occurs when i assign a new doc with my-index which was assigned to any other doc previously.

Comment: Can i get any answers

Comment: i have explained my scenario here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19470994/async-recursive-database-update-operation-in-with- thanks for any help